# How can I import a large list of tasks into Trello

Tags: trello, import, tasks

How can I import a  large list of tasks (.csv or .txt)  into Trello and convert into cards that are part of a list

Answer (score 29):

**This facility is now built in to Trello.**

1. Copy all your notes, one-per-line, to the clipboard
2. In a list in a Trello board, click on "Add"
3. Paste in all your lines, to this first new item
4. Click Add, or hit Enter, and Trello will create one new task per row,

Comment: This will get the multiple cards very quickly, though it doesn't allow you to add multiple fields.

Comment: This is [the help page](http://help.trello.com/article/751-importing-data-into-trello) of trello

Answer (score 4):

I've created and shared a Google Spreadsheet which you can use to import multiple entries. It's geared towards a Scrum product backlog, but you could customise it if you want. Details here: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-3-upload-existing-product-backlog-into-trello/

Comment: Thank you, this works great. It allowed me to import my backlog very easily.

Comment: Nice! This is the only option I've seen that allows you to import checklist items for your cards too. Is this script still working as of 2018?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [Import Wizard](https://wizard.import2.com), by Import2 (disclaimer, I work for Import2). This will import your data directly from CSV into a list in Trello.

Comment: Does Import2 allow you to import checklist items along with your cards too?

Comment: @SimonEast Unfortunately not at this time

Comment: Does not appear to support comments either (many-to-one with a card)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a free power-up which lets you import multiple cards from Excel/CSV files. This includes the ability to add all the standard Card fields and any Custom fields you have set up.
You can try it out here [Trello Import by Blue Cat](https://trello.com/power-ups/61fa6cd2cc14647c2c9ee821/trello-import-by-blue-cat).

Answer (score -2):

I assume you got this TXT or CSV file by exporting data from some other system. in some cases you can skip this intermediate step and transfer tasks between systems directly. one of the products that can do that is TaskAdapter: http://www.taskadapter.com.

e.g. here are steps for Trello and Atlassian JIRA integration: http://www.taskadapter.com/user-guide/trello/

or for JIRA and Microsoft Project: http://www.taskadapter.com/user-guide/atlassian-jira/atlassian-jira-and-microsoft-project-integration-step-by-step-guide/

(disclaimer: I am owner of TaskAdapter product)