# Automated Data Import to Trello

Tags: trello

An application form on my site is automatically transcribed to an Excel file. It also outputs a summary with attachments to an email address on our domain. Do you know of any way get this application data more efficiently imported to Trello, in terms of cards with attachments and sorting information? I am currently doing this manually on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/how-can-i-import-a-large-list-of-tasks-into-trello

Answer (score 1):

The Trello API is in its early stages. Other, simpler ways of getting structured data into Trello will probably emerge as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I've created and shared a Google Spreadsheet which you can use to import multiple entries. It's geared towards a Scrum product backlog, but you could customise it if you want.

Details here: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/online-scrum-tools-part-3-upload-existing-product-backlog-into-trello/

Comment: If you see a question where you can post an identical answer - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28762 - then that's a good sign that the questions are duplicate. You should flag the second question as a duplicate of the first rather than answering.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead create a Form that directly populates Trello, using the [Trello Forms Power-Up](https://trello.com/power-ups/6139de588901011c01baf52f/forms-by-blue-cat)

Or if you are keen on keeping to using a Spreadsheet you can then upload that with the [Trello Import Power-Up](https://trello.com/power-ups/61fa6cd2cc14647c2c9ee821/trello-import-by-blue-cat) although I don't think you can easily include attachments with that.