# How to import task lists into trello, exported from some other account of trello?

Tags: trello

I have exported board from one account of trello. Now I want to import that same on other account. I can't see any option to import the board. How can I do that???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I import a large list of tasks into Trello](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/how-can-i-import-a-large-list-of-tasks-into-trello)

Answer (score 1):

Trello export is for backup and your own analysis. It is not intended to be imported into another account. Rather, you should invite the other account to be a member of that board. If you need a completely new copy, you can sign in to the other account and copy the board using **Copy Board**.

Comment: I need this to import in my second account :(

Comment: Sorry, but why does that mean you cannot make the board visible to your second account and copy it?