# Is it possible to paste a bulleted list of text from Word into a checklist in Trello?

Tags: trello-cards

Is it possible to paste a bulleted list of text from Word into a checklist in Trello?  Or to import items into a checklist or card?

IMPORTANT: Not a list of TASKS, we need to import a bulleted list into a CHECKLIST.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19227/how-can-i-import-a-large-list-of-tasks-into-trello